# How effective is water purification by boiling?

Tags: microbiology, freshwater-biology

Does boiling water kill all harmful bacteria, fungus etc from water, or it is just a myth and removes only few of microorganism?

Answer (score 4):

To be precise, boiling water would not ***remove all bacteria*** as there are certain **[extremophiles that thrive at higher temperatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremophile)**.

However, **[boiling of water is known to get rid of harmful pathogens](http://cottagelife.com/environment/does-boiling-lake-water-kill-bacteria-and-viruses)**. Boiling of water is a method of **[pasteurization](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigvJvosKPUAhVD0GMKHRk2AksQFggwMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foodsafetysite.com%2Feducators%2Fcompetencies%2Fgeneral%2Ffoodprocessing%2Fprocessing2.html&usg=AFQjCNHGAxoYFxrfVSwCvT7kDKL6T1t7jQ&sig2=Mn2PKu3QPrgdcl5_IWVWJg)**, which means killing those organisms that ***can cause harm to humans***.

Quoting from **[New York State - Department of Health](https://www.health.ny.gov/environmental/water/drinking/boilwater/response_information_public_health_professional.htm)** >>

> Boiling water **kills or inactivates viruses, bacteria, protozoa and
>   other pathogens** by using *heat to damage structural components and
>   disrupt essential life processes* (e.g. denature proteins). Boiling is
>   not sterilization and is more accurately characterized as
>   pasteurization.
>
> Cooking food is also a form of pasteurization. For *pasteurization to
>   be effective, water or food must be heated to at least the
>   pasteurization temperature for the organisms of concern and held at
>   that temperature for a prescribed interval*.

Comment: What is the difference between sterilization and pasteurization?